# Incompatible type - generic interface and implementation

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, types

I have a generic interface defined as:

```
public interface Service<T extends Slicer, E extends Slice> {
}
```

And an implementation:

```
public class DynamoDbService implements Service<DynamoDbSlicer, DynamoDbSlice> {
}
```

If I try to instantiate `DynamoDbService` and assign it to a variable of type `Service<DynamoDbSlicer, DynamoDbSlice>` like so:

```
public class Test {

    private void test() {
        final Service<Slicer, Slice> service = new DynamoDbService();
    }
}
```

I get an `incompatible types` error:

```
Incompatible types.
Required: Service <Slicer, Slice>
Found: DynamoDbService
```

As `DynamoDbService` implements the generic interface, shouldn't this be ok? The following example without generics works how I'd expect and how I'd like the previous example to work:

```
public interface ThingInterface {
}

public class Thing implements ThingInterface {
}

private void thingTest() {
    final ThingInterface thingInteface = new Thing();
}
```

Comment: `Service<Slicer, Slice>` is not a valid super-type of `Service<DynamoDbSlicer, DynamoDbSlice>`. See [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2745265/5221149) for why.

Comment: You want `Service<DynamoDbSlicer, DynamoDbSlice> service`.

Comment: @rgettman Or `Service<? extends Slicer, ? extends Slice>`

Comment: @Andreas thanks very much, `? extends X` was the part I was missing. This got me most of the way there but I added a follow up question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56375349/generic-interface-and-implementation-type-cannot-be-converted